# open .php show blank page

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

There is my nginx error log:

```
2016/03/23 10:19:33 [error] 21614#0: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/dwj/phpblog/inc/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dwj/phpblog/inc/blade.php on line 2
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/dwj/phpblog/inc/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/dwj/phpblog/inc/blade.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 106.187.90.170, server: dwjdwj.cn, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "dwjdwj.cn"
```

And my code is in  https://github.com/openxyz/phpblog;

I think the code is well.There must be some wrong in my configure.

Comment: Your code is trying to find `autoload.php` within `vendor` folder at the root of your application (`phpblog`). But it is not present there.

Comment: yes.But the same code in my teacher's computer is fine.I guess the  autoload.php may be auto-generation.

Comment: This looks like a composer dependency. Have you installed [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and any additional files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that your project uses composer. Which means that you need to install and run composer to pull required files down into your vendor folder before the app will run. As a side effect, that also generates the autoload.php.

Have you run composer locally to get/generate the files you need?